# LaTeX doesn't execute the \ref and \label commands

Tags: cross-referencing

code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} % добавить leqno в [] для нумерации слева

%%% Работа с русским языком
\usepackage{cmap}                   % поиск в PDF
\usepackage{mathtext}               % русские буквы в формулах
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}           % кодировка
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % кодировка исходного текста
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} % локализация и переносы
%%% Дополнительная работа с математикой
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools} % AMS
\usepackage{icomma} % "Умная" запятая: $0,2$ --- число, $0, 2$ --- перечисление
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
%% Номера формул
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true} % Показывать номера только у тех формул, на которые есть \eqref{} в тексте.
\DeclareMathOperator{\bjbjb}{tg}
%% Шрифты
\usepackage{euscript}    % Шрифт Евклид
\usepackage{mathrsfs} % Красивый матшрифт

%% Номера формул
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true} % Показывать номера только у тех формул, на которые есть \eqref{} в тексте.
\newcommand{\lra}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\ua}{\Uparrow}
\newcommand{\da}{\Downarrow}

%% Шрифты
\usepackage{euscript}    % Шрифт Евклид
\usepackage{mathrsfs} % Красивый матшрифт

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
 \label{4} 
 \lim_{n\to\infty}
    \end{equation}
\ref{4}
   \[
   a^2+b^2=c^2
   \]
\end{document}
```

the final attude of the document:

[image]

Comment: How many times did you compile your document?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  If you remove the packages, does the labeling start showing up?  Are you getting anything from the `\ref`?  At the least, you should see `??` in the output.  (I would also recommend a more descriptive label than `4`, so that if this equation is no longer the fourth, you'll still be able to refer to it intelligently.)

Comment: yes, in case of removing some packages i obtain the result

Answer (score 18):

In your document, there is (twice) the line

```
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true}
```

which sets to `true` the option `showonlyrefs` from the package `mathtools`. When this option is used, only the equations which are actually referenced as equations in the text will show up. However, equations should be referenced with `\eqref`, not with `\ref`. Hence, in your example, `mathtools` thinks you did not reference your equation, so it does not number it and the reference `\ref{4}` is empty.

The label will show up in your example if you replace `\ref` with `\eqref`, or if you do not use the `showonlyrefs` option of `mathtools`.

To make it more explicit, here's your example with `\ref{4}` replaced with `\eqref{4}`, and the output.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} % добавить leqno в [] для нумерации слева

%%% Работа с русским языком
\usepackage{cmap}                   % поиск в PDF
\usepackage{mathtext}               % русские буквы в формулах
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}           % кодировка
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % кодировка исходного текста
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} % локализация и переносы
%%% Дополнительная работа с математикой
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools} % AMS
\usepackage{icomma} % "Умная" запятая: $0,2$ --- число, $0, 2$ --- перечисление
%% Номера формул
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true} % Показывать номера только у тех формул, на которые есть \eqref{} в тексте.
\DeclareMathOperator{\bjbjb}{tg}
\newcommand{\lra}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\ua}{\Uparrow}
\newcommand{\da}{\Downarrow}

%% Шрифты
\usepackage{euscript}    % Шрифт Евклид
\usepackage{mathrsfs} % Красивый матшрифт

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
 \label{4} 
 \lim_{n\to\infty}
    \end{equation}
\eqref{4}
   \[
   a^2+b^2=c^2
   \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's your example with both lines `\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true}` removed, and the output.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} % добавить leqno в [] для нумерации слева

%%% Работа с русским языком
\usepackage{cmap}                   % поиск в PDF
\usepackage{mathtext}               % русские буквы в формулах
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}           % кодировка
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % кодировка исходного текста
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} % локализация и переносы
%%% Дополнительная работа с математикой
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools} % AMS
\usepackage{icomma} % "Умная" запятая: $0,2$ --- число, $0, 2$ --- перечисление
\DeclareMathOperator{\bjbjb}{tg}
\newcommand{\lra}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\ua}{\Uparrow}
\newcommand{\da}{\Downarrow}

%% Шрифты
\usepackage{euscript}    % Шрифт Евклид
\usepackage{mathrsfs} % Красивый матшрифт

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
 \label{4} 
 \lim_{n\to\infty}
    \end{equation}
\ref{4}
   \[
   a^2+b^2=c^2
   \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the aid. I copied your example and tried to compile that, but references still didn't show up

Comment: I've removed that package and obtain a victory! Thanks a lot!